# How to concatenate new vectors into existing Bert vector?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding, bert-language-model, word-embedding

For a sentence,I may extract a few entities and each of the entities is embedded with 256 dimension vectors. Then I compute an average for these entities to be a single vector to represent these entity representations.

Now, I want to concatenate the bert's 'pooled output' layer with this entity vector together as input of the next layer. This might improve the original Bert's performance. How to do this in Keras?

This is the fine-tune code to define a text classifier model from a tutorial:

```
def build_classifier_model():
  text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
  
  encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
  encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
  outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
  net = outputs['pooled_output']
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
  net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
  return tf.keras.Model(text_input, net)
```

How to combine the pooled_output of 512 dimension with the entity vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to ensure that the vector with whom you want to concatenate has the same dimension on the axis you want to concatenate (e.g. `(512,1)` `(512,1)` -> `(1024,1)`).

Then you could use:
`tf.keras.layers.Concatenate([pooled_output,entity_layer],axis=axis)`

on the desired axis.

You can also have a look here for more details: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate

Comment: Hi, Timbus, It seems simple, but my entity vector length is different from the bert vector. For concatenation, two vectors don't have to be the same length. Right?

Comment: No they do not have to be of the same length, just ensure the axis on which you concatenate is of the same dimension (i.e. in the example above axis=1)

Comment: You can concatenate (1536,1) with (512,1) to give you (2048,1) but you cannot concatenate (1536,5) with (512,1).

Comment: I hope the examples presented in the comment section help you :D

Comment: Yes, it should be similar to (1536,1) with (512,1).

Comment: BTW, the 'pooled_vector' is supposed to represent the whole sentence's vector in Bert. Right? I hope I am using the right layer to concatenate with entity vector. This is for text classification.

Comment: This is more complicated, but here I took the explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61331991/bert-pooled-output-is-different-from-first-vector-of-sequence-output have a look at the accepted answer.

Comment: The intention of pooled_output and sequence_output are different. Since, the embeddings from the BERT model at the output layer are known to be contextual embeddings, the output of the 1st token, i.e, [CLS] token would have captured sufficient context. Hence, the authors of BERT paper found it sufficient to use only the output from the 1st token for few tasks such as classification. They call this output from the single token (i.e, 1st token) as  pooled_output.

Comment: Assuming that you are doing classification (as I can see in your code) then the pooled output would be the first token, but apparently it was found to capture enough context.

Comment: Good to know and confirmed,  although still don't understand why the very first artificial token is sufficient to capture the whole sentence's meaning.

Comment: @marlon since you accepted my answer as the solving one, would you mind also upvoting it? It helps both me and the others who run into the issue. Thank you.